# Start Splash screen every time if user press home button or back button from main activity

Tags: android, splash-screen

I have two activity. 
1] splash screen
2]MainActivity

Once splash screen task over it moves to next MainActivity..
But my requirement is ..If user press home button or backPress . and when user resume application again,it should start with splash screen,not from MainActivity.

thankx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am seeing every answer here says to override the `onResume()` method. This is a bad idea. Why? Well, when you are in the `MainActivity` and you get a call, you can still see the activity in the background, as it is in the `onPause()` state. When you dismiss the call, `onResume()` will be called and then `SplashActivity` will be called. This is not a good user experience and not what you might be looking for.

Also, `onResume()` gets called during the creation of `MainActivity`. So if you put the `startActivity()` code in `onResume()` without any conditional check, you will never see `MainActivity` itself. `SplashActivity` will start immediately when `MainActivity` is created.

So, how to accomplish what you want?

1. Once you start `MainActivity` from `SplashActivity`, don't `finish()` the `SplashActivity`. Let it remain in the back stack, so when you press back button, you will go to `SplashActivity`.
2. In the `onStop()` method of your `MainActivity` set a flag to note that `MainActivity` is minimized. Then in `onStart()` check for this flag and start `SplashActivity` only if this flag is set. This is to make sure that the app is minimized and is resuming.

**MainActivity**:

```
 private boolean isMinimized = false;

 @Override
 protected void onStop() {
      super.onStop();
      isMinimized = true;
 }

 @Override
 protected void onStart() {
      super.onStart();

      if(isMinimized){
          startActivity(new Intent(this , SplashActivity.class));
          isMinimized = false;
          finish();
      }
 }
```

Comment: When Home button is pressed.. and when user resume app..splash screen should start

Comment: You need to startAcitivity in `onStart` based on the flag that you set in the `onStop`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't finish your Activity before starting the new one you will get back to the Splash Activity on back press.

Override OnResume and start your splash Activity for starting it from splash whenever application is resumed.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    startActivity(new Intent(this , SplashActivity.class));
    finish();
}
```

Just like this ...

Answer (score 1):

1. For home button pressed

Use `Home` as *category* in *intent-filter*  of your `SplashScreen` AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<intent-filter>
 ....
 //-- this will show up your app when home button pressed (like laucher)
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
</intent-filter>
```

2. For Back button pressed

Override them with intent to Splash Screen

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    startActivity(new Intent(this , SplashActivity.class));
    finish();
}
```

3. OnResume

   Before coming to running state `OnResume` is called according to [this](http://www.javatpoint.com/images/androidimages/Android-Activity-Lifecycle.png) so if you called some other activity at `onResume` current will not even start it will directly do to intent declared,

Comment: i have changed answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this code inside your MainActivity

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        startActivity(new Intent(this , SplashActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
```

**Edit** You can use flag to detect the first time when `onResume` is called

```
int flag = 0;
```

and change your onResume code to below :

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(flag == 0) {
            flag = 1 ;
        }
        else {
            flag = 1 ;
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Isn't it going to load like SplashAct --> MainAct --> SplashAct --> MainAct ..... infinite time ?

Comment: It is doing like that only